# How to use laravel [webhook] notification with on-demand notifications?

Tags: laravel

I've designed a system that users can add multiple notification channels and webhook is one of them. I can use other notification drivers with on-demand notifications but webhook is not working.

For example, when I create a notification like this:

```php
Notification::route('slack', 'my slack webhook url')->notify(new MyNotification());
```

It works, it sends a message to my slack.

But when I try this with webhook:

```php
Notification::route('webhook', 'my webhook url')->notify(new MyNotification());
```

It's not sending any post requests and I couldn't figure it out.

This is the code from the package (https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webhook). I've checked and `$url` is always null but when it comes to slack, `$url` is not null.

```php
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @param \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     *
     * @throws \NotificationChannels\Webhook\Exceptions\CouldNotSendNotification
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        if (! $url = $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('Webhook')) {
            return;
        }
        $webhookData = $notification->toWebhook($notifiable)->toArray();
        $response = $this->client->post($url, [
            'body' => json_encode(Arr::get($webhookData, 'data')),
            'verify' => false,
            'headers' => Arr::get($webhookData, 'headers'),
        ]);
        if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 300 || $response->getStatusCode() < 200) {
            throw CouldNotSendNotification::serviceRespondedWithAnError($response);
        }
    }
```

And this code from the slack notification channel (https://github.com/laravel/slack-notification-channel) surprisingly it's sending messages to my slack, but the code is same as the webhook package's code.

```php
/**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface|null
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        if (!$url = $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('slack', $notification)) {
            return;
        }

        return $this->http->post($url, $this->buildJsonPayload(
            $notification->toSlack($notifiable)
        ));
    }
```

How is that possible? Am I missing something? Why slack works but not the webhook?